# Ember JS CollectionArray Flickering

Tags: ember.js

When you have a large collection of objects in an ArrayController, you can sometimes see the list gradually building on the page when you switch to that view.

Is there a way to only show the view after the list has been built, in order to avoid a flickering interface?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to only show the view after the list has been built, in order to avoid a flickering interface?

It sounds like what you need is Ember.ListView - it improves performance for very large collections by rendering just enough rows to fill the visible area.

```
{{#collection Ember.ListView contentBinding="controller" height=500 rowHeight=50}}
  <!-- row content here -->
{{/collection}}
```

- Demo on jsbin: http://jsbin.com/ucegit/1/edit
- https://github.com/emberjs/list-view

Comment: Thanks for that solution, but I am actually rendering a bunch of floating divs that wrap around. I don't think this solution will help with this scenario?

Comment: I have hosted my code on amazone (link below), if you click on a user and then a table and click through all of the menus (menu 6 in particular, you will see how the lists of products are getting built really slowly, resulting in a flickering effect. I am really not sure what is causing this. [Example Flickering Code on AWS](http://ec2-50-17-93-135.compute-1.amazonaws.com:3000/pos)

Comment: Also, if you see the peepcode ember tutorial where they make a simple pos system, you can see some interface flicker while switching tables. Is there any way to prevent this, it is a bit of a blocker for me